# Use isset to add to an array

Tags: php

I would like a new item to be added to an array if a button is pressed

This is my code...

```
$engineers = array();

if(isset($_POST['add_user'])){
    $engineers[] = $_POST['engineer'];
    $array_count = count($engineers);
}
```

All it does is replace the only item in the array rather than add to it, where am I going wrong?

Thanks

The form used is

```
$dropdown = '<select id="engineer" name="engineer" class="select_engineer" type="text" name="engineer" /><option>Select Diary</option>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['user_name']}'>{$row['user_name']}</option>";
}
$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
```

">

(The list of engineers is populated from a MySQL database).

There isn't anywhere else that adds to the array, I just want a button that will add the engineers user name to the array

Comment: It's only ever going to run once, and add the contents of `$_POST['engineer']` to the array - where else are you adding things to `$engineers`?

Comment: Please also insert the code for your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your array resets every time you reload the page.
you have to store the data in cookies or sessions or database or ...
simple idea :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['engineers']))
$engineers = array();
else
$engineers = unserialize($_SESSION['engineers']);
if(isset($_POST['add_user'])){
    $engineers[] = $_POST['engineer'];
    $array_count = count($engineers);
}
$_SESSION['engineers'] = serialize($engineers);
```

Comment: That makes complete sense, never thought about the page refreshing on the form submit.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you're having Client / Server communication each time a button is pressed, you're gonna have to use [Session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Whenever you have a client/server request, a new thread is created in your Web Server, which has no idea what happened in other threads. If the client clicked a button and sent an information to the server that was added to a variable and then got his answer, all that was in PHP memory was deleted already.
If you want to go to the server, go back to the client, back to the server and so on, you're gonna have to store the information somewhere, somehow. It might be useful to use a Session to store everything and at the end of it do something, like e-commerces.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime your submit the form the whole code is re-executed. Which means  `$engineers` is set to an empty array everytime. The submitted data is added to this empty array, which means it will be the only data available.

Use `$_SESSION` for persistence.